# perlbrew: installing a perl module locally

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I've got `perlbrew` installed on OS X fine, and can install Perl modules from CPAN, using `cpanm` no problem.

But, now I'm attempting to install a Perl module provided from a software vendor, and that PM is not on CPAN - you download it from their application and install it "locally".

How can I do this with `perlbrew`?

The documentation states to do a direct install, download the tar.gz file, extract it, then:

```bash
$ cd Infoblox-xxxxxxx/
$ perl Makefile.PL
... misc output here
$ make
... misc output here
$ make install
... misc output here
```

But if I do this, I guess it will install it for the OS Perl version, not my `perlbrew` install.

The other option mentioned is to create a local CPAN site and add the appliance URL (to grab the Perl module) to the list of sites. Is this possible with `perlbrew`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```bash
$ cd Infoblox-xxxxxxx/
$ perl Makefile.PL
... insert misc output here ...

$ make
... insert misc output here ...

$ make install
... insert misc output here ...
```

But if I do this, I guess it will install it for the OS Perl version, not my perlbrew install.

If you are using `perlbrew` to select your `perl`, it should install in the appropriate location for the `perl` you selected.

`which perl` will tell you which `perl` you are using.

If you want to use a specific `perl` without leaving things to `perlbrew`, you can always invoke the specific `perl` you want using its full path:

```
 cd Infoblox-xxxxxxx/
 ~/perl5/.../bin/perl Makefile.PL
 make
 make install
```

Comment: Yes ! That was simple. Being new to perlbrew, it threw me when I had to install a module not through cpanm! Thanks. ;-)

Comment: @kpw, they key is just to remember that `perlbrew` changes what binary is pointed to by `perl` on your commandline, and the install scripts all rely on the currently-executing `perl` to figure out where to install stuff. That was baked in to the binary when you installed via `perlbrew`.

Comment: You should do `perlbrew list` to see which version of Perl is active. Also, `perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper \@INC'` will show you where `perl` will search for modules.